# What happens if I use relatively short burrs (55mm) to grind lightly roasted coffee as opposed to longer (65mm+) ones?

Tags: espresso, flavor, grinder

I am making the first steps towards drinking a decent/good coffee at home (where I also work). My shortlist was composed of Lelit-PL72, MACAP M42M, EUREKA MIGNON SPECIALITA 16CR, and Eureka Mignon XL 65.

After reading through forums and seeing product reviews, I favor the Eureka ones, but I am not sure how to choose between them.

I know that Mignon XL has longer burrs (65mm) as opposed to MIGNON SPECIALITA's 55mm and I remember to have read somewhere that **for lightly roasted coffee (which I prefer), longer burrs are preferred.**

Since this is my first (kind of) professional grinder, I would not want to buy something as expensive as Mignon XL, unless there is a significant difference in results between the two.

What happens if I choose to grind lightly roasted coffee with shorter burrs? Is it going to take longer (which I do not mind), wear the burrs more (not important either, since I would not go beyond 3 double espressos per day), feel a significant difference in texture or taste?

Comment: Welcome to Coffee :D Are you going to be using the grinder for espresso only or do you want to use it for filter coffee / French press as well?

Comment: @JJJ Virtually expresso only.

Comment: Yea I think the ones you mentioned are geared to espresso mostly or exclusively. Some grinders do both but it's a bit of a hassle when you switch from really coarse to very fine, for example there may be retention. And some might say that those grinders covering a broad range don't excel at any specific grind. Anyway, interesting question, I hadn't heard those considerations about burr length before.